# Question regarding geometric series exercice

Tags: geometric-series

I have the following sum:

$$ S = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \frac{1 + 2^n}{3^n} $$

So I tried the following:

$$ S = \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \frac{1}{3^n} + \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} \frac{2^n}{3^n} = 
\sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} (\frac{1}{3})^n + \sum^{\infty}_{n = 1} (\frac{2}{3})^n$$

And here, applying the formula for each summatory with $a = 1$ and $r_1 = \frac{1}{3} $ and $r_2 = \frac{2}{3}$ gives me $ \frac{3}{2} $ and $3$ respectively. However, $\frac{9}{2}$ is not the correct answer. I would like to know which is the wrong step here, for me it seems everything looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series are
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{3^n}=\frac{1/3}{1-1/3}=\frac12,
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigg(\frac23\bigg)^n=\frac{2/3}{1-2/3}=2.
$$
Most likely you calculated as if the sums started from $n=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Where does this formula come from? I noted that I can also simply remove the first term and it works.

Comment: The same argument that lets you calculate a geometric series starting at zero lets you calculate a geometric series starting at any positive integer.

Comment: I see, thanks Martin